# Asara Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred ten?

### ?עשרה ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 310.

There is lazy gematria on this one, but leave it alone.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred nine entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uktzin 3:12:

> R. Yehoshua ben Levi said: In the World to Come the Holy One, Blessed be He, will make each righteous person to inherit 310 worlds, for it is written: "That I may cause those who love Me to inherit 'yesh' (310) and that I may fill their treasuries" (Mishlei 8:21).

Comment: That was quick.

Answer (score 6):

[Sefer Hamaor Al HaRambam](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34304&st=&pgnum=222&hilite=) says that a year has 365 days. When you take away Shabbos and Yom Tov days you remain with 310. This is [the 310 worlds each Tzadik will get](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22868/5) - that the regular days will be rest days like Shabbos.

See [HaDeos V'Hamidos - note on bottom](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49353&hilite=7e6f8175-f0c3-46a2-bb91-ed4526102c0e&st=%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%A9+%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA+%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%A8) for calculation of 310 days.